# how to show photos on my .blade view page from mysql database specific to id

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, image

I am building a classified website and I am trying to set it up to show one photo from the database on the main page, that same photo on a category page, but when you view the full page of the item for sale I want to show all of the photos in that section.

Like how ebay shows one photo for the ad but when you click the ad it shows several photos.

I have used 'strtok' to show the single photo in my main page and category page but now I don't know how to setup the view page to show all the photos for that item.

here is how I am saving the images when the listing is posted.

```
public function postHobbies(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, [
    'photos' => 'required',
    'Photos.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg, png, jpeg, gif, aae, heif, svg|max:2048'
  ]);

  $ads = new Listings;
  $images = $request->file('photos');
  $count = 0;
  if ($request->file('photos')) {
    foreach ($images as $item) {
      if ($count < 6) {
        $var = date_create();
        $date = date_format($var, 'Ymd');
        $imageName = $date . '_' . $item->getClientOriginalName();
        $item->move(public_path() . '/uploads/', $imageName);
        $url = URL::to("/") . '/uploads/' . $imageName;
        $arr[] = $url;
        $count++;
      }
    }
    $image = implode(",", $arr);
    $ads->photos = $image;
    $ads->save();
    return redirect('/')->with('info', 'Listing published successfully');
  }
}
```

here is my controller for the page I am trying to post all of the photos on

```
public function view(Request $request, $id)
{
  $ads = DB::table('listings')
    ->select('listings.id', 'photos', 'description', 'year', 'make', 'model', 'price', 'city', 'state', 'email')
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->get();
  $output = '';
  if ($ads->count() > 0) {
    return view('users.posted.postedads', ['id' => $id, 'ads' => $ads]);
  }
}
```

And finally here is how I am currently passing it which is just showing me the single photo since I am still using the 'strtok' to make sure it works. So i assume i need to change this function i just don't know what to use or how to use it.

```
<div class="row">
@if(count($ads)>0)
  @foreach($ads as $row)
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="productCard">
      <img style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="<?php echo strtok($row->photos, ',')?>" />
    </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
@else
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to save many images, you are saving only one image now.

It is recommended to make another model for images (for example `Image`), and make [one to many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations) or [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationships between `Listings`(it is better to user singular name for models).

Then, in your `view` method you need to retrieve related models with `Listings->with('images')` and in your view file, you need add another foreach loop where you want to display images.

View code would be something like this:

```
<div class="row">
@if(count($ads)>0)
  @foreach($ads as $row)
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="productCard">
      @foreach($row->images as $image)
      <img style="width:100%; height:100%;" src="{{ $image->url }}" />
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
@else
@endif
```

**Note** I used  `{{ }}` Laravel Blade directive instead of `<?php echo`, you should too

Comment: I will try this. Looking in my files now though it is saving all of the images to my uploads folder.

Comment: Actually your code uploads files properly, but you don't have any information about, which image belongs to which ad, so because of it you need to make relationship between image and `Listing` model

Comment: for example if i go like this   <h3>{{$row->photos}}</h3> the website prints 
    https://www.needsatrailer.com/uploads/20200330_EDCC71CC-9260-4216-AE6F- 
    DE0A6649AA21.jpeg,https://www.needsatrailer.com/uploads/20200330_996E7278- 
    7649-431A-8281- 
    08206ADBC8D6.jpeg,https://www.needsatrailer.com/uploads/20200330_DB38E617- 
    2056-471F-A4CA- 
    21E44DAF456D.jpeg,https://www.needsatrailer.com/uploads/20200330_866697B5- 
    2426-497C-9B22-6F48C68AC620.jpeg  which is what i want just as img not <h3>

Comment: On that case, you need to split `$row-photos` using `str_split` or `explode`

Comment: okay yeah thats what i was looking for. how would i go about putting the str_split in there

Comment: Check the documentation: `str_split` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php
`explode` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php